# Problem in the meaning of "not dominated by an integrable function"

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

> Let $\Omega =(0,1)$ equipped with the Borel sets and Lebesgue measure. Let $\alpha\in (1,2)$ and $X_n=n^\alpha \chi_{(1/(n+1), 1/n)}\rightarrow 0$ a.s. Show that Theorem 1.6.8 can be applied with $h(x)=x$ and $g(x)=|x|^{2/\alpha}$, **but the $X_n$ are not dominated by an integrable function**.

I did not understand the bold part i.e. "but the $X_n$ are not dominated by an integrable function" and why $X_n=n^\alpha \chi_{(1/(n+1), 1/n)}\rightarrow 0$ a.s.. Surely $n^{\alpha}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. But $\chi_{(1/(n+1), 1/n)}\rightarrow $ zero measure set. So $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n$ is like a infinity stick on the point $0$.

In rigorous process:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n|>\epsilon)< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{EX_n^2}{\epsilon^2}$$
which is clearly not a finite quantity. So I could not come to a conclusion.

If we put this problem aside what does **but the $X_n$ are not dominated by an integrable function** means?

> **Theorem 1.6.8:** *Suppose $X_n\rightarrow X$ a.s.. Let $g, h$ be continuous functions with*
>
> *(i)* $g\geq 0$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$.
>
> *(ii)* $|h(x)|/g(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.
>
> *and (iii)* $Eg(X_n)\leq K <\infty$ for all $n$.
>
> *Then $Eh(X_n)\to Eh(X)$.*

Again, **I do not need the proof of the application of the theorem, I need to know what means only the bold part.**

Comment: It means that if a measurable $f$ is such that $|X_n| \le f$ then $f$ is not integrable, that is, $\int f = \infty$.

Comment: oh! Thanks @copper.hat , can you tell anything about almost sure part?

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to?

Comment: @copper.hat It says *"$X_n=n^\alpha \chi_{(1/(n+1), 1/n)}\rightarrow 0$ a.s."*, why is this true?

Comment: @MANMAID Because any $x\in (0,1)$ is in at most one $(1/(n+1),1/n).$

Comment: @MANMAID: In fact for **any** $\omega \in \Omega$ we have $X_n(\omega) \neq 0$ for at most a finite number of indices, so $X_n(\omega) \to 0$ everywhere. This is true because if $n > { 1\over \omega}$, then $X_n(\omega) = 0$.